# In GHC.Prim, why can pointer operations fail with an unchecked exception?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm doing a literature review about the use of pointers in functional languages and I came across the [following](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.5.3/GHC-Prim.html#g:26) comment in the `GHC.Prim` documentation:

```
reallyUnsafePtrEquality# :: a -> a -> Int#

Returns 1# if the given pointers are equal and 0# otherwise.

Warning: this can fail with an unchecked exception.
```

I understand that there are a lot of ways to misuse this function but why does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer in the GHC source code: https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/prelude/primops.txt.pp#L3199-L3233

It turns out that it cannot throw an exception but the function is marked as throwing so that GHC won't move it.